# I have DHCP server on firewall if i want Create Active Directory server for the network In that case can i keep DHCP on firewall?

Tags: windows, server, active-directory, dhcp

DHCP server runs on firewall, when i create AD server, it is possible to create AD keeping the DHCP

I need to setup AD without creating the DHCP server

Comment: Of course you can: even if the DHCP Microsoft service allows you to create fail-over DHCP clusters and offers advanced options as an advanced management interface, it is not essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. When installing AD roles not check the DHCP role so your AD joined computer will still get their IP addresses from the firewall.